# Происхождение слова "чернила"

Tags: этимология

-

Answer (score 4):

В памятниках письменности слово **ЧЕРНИЛА** отмечается с XI в. в виде **чьрнило** «черная краска для письма». Стар. форма ед. ч. *чьрнило* сохранилась в укр. яз. (с переходом ь > е и далее после ч — в гласн. **о**). В рус. яз. соврем. форма **чернила** представляет собой застывший им. п. мн. ч. с изменением в слове кратк. гласн. ь в е. 
Др.-рус. слово **чьрнило** является семант. соответствием (калькой) ср.-греч. melan «черный», «чернила». Ср. от этого греч. слова в рус. яз. термин *меланхолия* «мрачная 
настроенность, уныние», букв. «черная желчь» (греч. chole «желчь»). 
Слово чернила «черная краска» впоследствии, как видим, расширило свое знач. Для калькирования греч. melan, как уже отмечено, было использовано др.-рус. слово **чьрнило**. Это слово праслав. по происхождению. Первонач., вероятно, оно имело форму *čьrnidlo > чьрнило «то, чем чернят», образованную с суф. -dlo от глаг.* čьrniti > чернить, в свою очередь производного от прил. *čьrnъ «черный» (как бел — белить), давшего соврем. полную форму **черный** (ь > е). (Словарь Цыганенко)

Comment: С возвращением, olsa! Приятно снова видеть Вас на форуме.

Comment: Спасибо, Ларf! Изменился график работы, сейчас редко бываю в сети. Скучаю по форуму :-))